# Codable Issue If Dictionary is Empty

Tags: swift, codable

I am trying to make use of Codable protocol with swift
Issue is I need to dequeue nested dictionary getting from server. Suppose 
Data : its values and inside data one more dictionary Goal 
if goal inside data has a value it works fine 
but in case goal inside Dictionary turns out to be empty it says 
Error - The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

My JSON Response 
case 1 - Without Goal - Issue facing

```
{
  "code": "1",
  "message": "Data fetched successfully",
  "data": {
    "id": "2",
    "organization_id": "2",
    "first_name": "iOS",
    "last_name": "test",
    "user_name": "iOS",
    "email": "ios@gmail.com",
    "password": "4399578cc31cf62535a7dba566e4aea0",
    "security_hash": "fdf4d3bb5731de23b42771e01d9e0c3e",
    "google_id": "525256562",
    "facebook_id": "525256562",
    "access_code": "iosTest1",
    "gender": "",
    "contact": "1234567890",
    "user_profile": "",
    "profile_thumb": "",
    "dob": "",
    "weight": "",
    "height": "",
    "is_corporate": "0",
    "status": "1",
    "created_at": "2018-04-19 10:37:46",
    "updated_at": "2018-12-10 15:32:59",
    "profile_image_url": "",
    "goal": {}
  }
}
```

case 2: When Goal has values

```
{
  "code": "1",
  "message": "Data fetched successfully",
  "data": {
    "id": "2",
    "organization_id": "2",
    "first_name": "iOS",
    "last_name": "test",
    "user_name": "ios",
    "email": "ios@gmail.com",
    "password": "4399578cc31cf62535a7dba566e4aea0",
    "security_hash": "fdf4d3bb5731de23b42771e01d9e0c3e",
    "google_id": "525256562",
    "facebook_id": "525256562",
    "access_code": "iosTest1",
    "gender": "",
    "contact": "1234567890",
    "user_profile": "",
    "profile_thumb": "",
    "dob": "",
    "weight": "",
    "height": "",
    "is_corporate": "0",
    "status": "1",
    "created_at": "2018-04-19 10:37:46",
    "updated_at": "2018-12-10 15:32:59",
    "profile_image_url": "",
    "goal": {
      "id": "4",
      "client_id": "2",
      "ambition_to_achieve": "adfadf",
      "current_assessment": "dfadfafa",
      "expected": "fasdfasdfsafsf",
      "expected_date": "2018-12-15",
      "description": "asdfadsfadf",
      "goal_status": "1",
      "created_at": "2018-12-12 18:15:36",
      "updated_at": ""
    }
  }
}
```

///--- Main Class Which handle main Data

```
struct LoggedUser: Codable {
    var dob, weight, height: String?
    let accesscode, contact, contactcode, email, facebookid: String?
    let firstname, gender, googleid, id, iscorporate, lastname: String?
    let organizationid, password, profilethumb, securityhash, status: String?
    let username, userprofile : String?
    let goal:Goal?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case accesscode="access_code"
        case contact, dob, email, gender, height, id, password, status, weight, goal
        case contactcode="contact_code"
        case facebookid="facebook_id"
        case firstname="first_name"
        case googleid="google_id"
        case iscorporate="is_corporate"
        case lastname="last_name"
        case organizationid="organization_id"
        case profilethumb="profile_thumb"
        case securityhash="security_hash"
        case username="user_name"
        case userprofile="user_profile"
    }
}
```

/// ---> Class For Goal

```
struct Goal: Codable {
    let id, clientID, ambitionToAchieve, currentAssessment: String?
    let expected, expectedDate, description, goalStatus: String?
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case clientID = "client_id"
        case ambitionToAchieve = "ambition_to_achieve"
        case currentAssessment = "current_assessment"
        case expected
        case expectedDate = "expected_date"
        case description
        case goalStatus = "goal_status"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}
```

----> Update
Just a correction 
Posting actual response

```
Get My Goal API Response ==> ["code": 1, "message": Data fetched successfully, "data": {
    "access_code" = iosTest4;
    contact = 1111111111;
    "contact_code" = 91;
    "created_at" = "2019-02-12 14:42:34";
    dob = "1996-05-10";
    email = "testing@email.com";
    "facebook_id" = "";
    "first_name" = iOS;
    gender = 1;
    goal =     (
    );
    "google_id" = "";
    height = "5.10";
    id = 35;
    "is_corporate" = 0;
    "last_name" = test;
    "organization_id" = 0;
    password = 915729f1e48bda300dabaac7d1ac8358;
    "profile_image_url" = "";
    "profile_thumb" = "";
    "security_hash" = 991f5cd86be6fc485633d1946dc84a7a;
    status = 1;
    "updated_at" = "2019-02-14 16:25:01";
    "user_name" = "testing@email.com";
    "user_profile" = "";
    weight = "0.10";
}]
```

Comment: **Never** `print(error.localizedDescription)` when catching `Decodable` errors. Print always the `error` instance. You get a very comprehensive message describing the error in detail.

Comment: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. This is what gets printed

Comment: Really? Even when you `print(error)`

Comment: Error ==> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "goal", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: As I said, the error message is pretty clear. `goal` is an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: But when it have value it return me a dictionary not array. So, Is there any way-out that we can cast goal as [String:Any] before codable

Comment: The compiler says it does not. Please edit the question and post a JSON (not an API response) considering all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was getting 2 Different Formats 
when Goal is empty it gives me an array
when had some value it returns a Dictionary 
So I Explicitly Created my Own Data() by manually Casting goal as [String:Any]

```
var loginDataDict = jsonDict["data"] as! [String:Any]
if let goalData = loginDataDict["goal"] as? [String:Any] {
   loginDataDict.updateValue(goalData, forKey: "goal")
} else {
   loginDataDict.updateValue([:], forKey: "goal")
}
```

This Might not  be a proper solution but may help someone if having same scenario as I had here